# How to substitute Scaled column with usual columns in my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have scaled columns, however how do I put them back into my data frame?
Here is the code that I have:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
num_cols = ['fare_amount','trip_distance','jfk_drop_distance','lga_drop_distance','ewr_drop_distance','met_drop_distance','wtc_drop_distance']
features = train_df[num_cols]
ct = ColumnTransformer([('scaler',
                        StandardScaler(),
                       ['fare_amount','trip_distance','jfk_drop_distance','lga_drop_distance','ewr_drop_distance','met_drop_distance','wtc_drop_distance'])]
                       ,remainder='passthrough')
ct.fit_transform(features)
```

My main data frame that I want to substite this columns with old one is train_data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, U seem to be almost close.

just put the fit_transform data to your dataframe like below:

```
...
train_df[num_cols] = ct.fit_transform(features)
...
```